# How do I get the URL from a iframe div tag using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am getting my URL source dynamically; see the code below. Can I get the URL in my `gettingiframe` div, which is inside an iframe?

Here's the code:

```
<div id="gettingiframe">
   <iframe src="http://google.com">
     <a href="http://gmail.com">gmail</a>
        <div id="my_div">
     <a href="http://facebook">facebook</a>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Can I get the anchor tag URL from inside `<div id="my_div">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in jQuery:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("a").attr("href");
```

P.S.: This will work if your `iframe` source is part of the same domain. If that belongs to an external domain (like in your example), you will not be able to retrieve the value (read about [same-origin policy](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy))

Comment: The question seems to be asking about the alternative content for browsers that don't support frames, not about the document loaded into the frame.

Comment: Gosh!! I really could not understand the question then. I thought the OP needed to access the anchor tag URL lying in the iframe.

Comment: @Quentin Where can you find the question about browser that don't support frames? (btw. which one doesn't?)

Comment: @FabioPoloni — The code in the question shows the HTML between the iframe start tag and the iframe end tag. That is how you provide alternate content. Browsers that don't support frames include lynx (which does support them but turning them into links but also displays the alternative content), Netscape 1, and last time I checked Opera allowed the user to turn off frame support.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, ***now*** I understand. I guessed the HTML inside the `iframe` is the *external* content.

Comment: yes  HTML inside the iframe is the external content